# LinkedIn webscraping selenium issue

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

**Element `<div class="block mt2">` is not showing up when searching in output of print(soup).**

```
# Scrap the data of 1 LinkedIn profile, write the data to a csv file 
wd.get(https://www.linkedin.com/company/pacific-retail-capital-partners/)
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, "html.parser")
soup
```

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
<html class="theme theme--mercado artdeco windows" lang="en"><head>
<script type="application/javascript">!function(i,n){void 0!==i.addEventListener&&void 0!==i.hidden&&(n.liVisibilityChangeListener=function(){i.hidden&&(n.liHasWindowHidden=!0)},i.addEventListener("visibilitychange",n.liVisibilityChangeListener))}(document,window);</script>
<title>LinkedIn</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta class="mercado-icons-sprite" content="https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/7438dbnn8galtczp2gk2s4bgb" id="artdeco-icons/static/images/sprite-asset" name="asset-url"/>
<meta content="" name="description"/>
<meta content="notranslate" name="google"/>
<meta content="voyager-web" name="service"/>
```

HTML inspect

```
<div class="block mt2">
    <div>
    <h1 id="ember30" class="ember-view t-24 t-black t-bold
        full-width" title="Pacific Retail Capital Partners">
      <span dir="ltr">Pacific Retail Capital Partners</span>
    </h1>
```

Since the html document is loaded in our script. We can scrape the name of the company using the div tag.

```
info_div = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'block mt2'})
print(info_div)
```

**Output is null. I am not getting any information printed.**
Can you explain what's happening and needed to be rectified.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `find()` method doesn't support multiple class name.
Use the following `css selector select_one()` to get the company details.

```
info_div = soup.select_one('div.block.mt2')
print(info_div.text)
```

or to get company name only use this.

```
  company = soup.select_one('div.block.mt2 h1>span')
  print(company.text)
```

---

If you still want use `find()` method then try with this.

```
info_div = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'mt2'})
print(info_div.text)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it's still showing ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Can you please `print(soup)` and check html content you have posted is present there? It seems you don't have that element. Before call this line provide some wait `soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, "html.parser")`

Comment: Yes, it's showing. I'll add it in the decription above

Comment: @yashagarwal : `print(soup)` this and try to search the element `<div class="block mt2">`

Comment: I also suspected this. Being an amateur I ignored it. The element not showing up in searches. Any advice?

Comment: @yashagarwal : Are you using chrome headless mode?

Comment: found a solution on another post which worked. Had to insert ```driver.quit()``` before passing the html parser command. Don't know how but it works @KunduK